# How to remove commas and show values in list formate in DropDownList in asp.net

Tags: c#, sql, asp.net

[image]

I have database table, in table one column is saved data like this-Karate,KickBoxing,KungFu,Yoga
i want show them in dropdownlist like this-

- Karate
- KickBoxing
- KungFu
- Yoga

How it possible,Can help me

Comment: “Help me” [is not a question we can answer](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/226103/).

Answer (score 0):

you always can use split to create a list, like:

var myData = "Karate,KickBoxing,KungFu,Yoga".Split(',').ToList();
You can bind the array to the DropDownList

[See on dotnetfiddle](https://dotnetfiddle.net/CBsFqj)

Comment: OP edited their question so that each item is a separate bullet in a list. I don't think this is what they're after.

Comment: Thanks..,But i want show them in DropDonlist like list @Juan S.Montoya

Comment: He changes the question, I update my answer.

Comment: You update your answer but it can not work in code.@Juan S.Montoya it can't work like dropdownList